# Displaying multer (music) files in index.ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

Recently I asked a question regarding saving files uploaded via multer into mongodb. I was able to get that to work but I am unable to display the file in my index.ejs. For example, I uploaded a music file and when I tried to display it in index.ejs by wrapping the audio tag around the path, it shows the audio controls but the play button is disabled and the volume icon has a slash across it. Please see my code.

routes.js

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
 cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var originalname = file.originalname;
    var extension = originalname.split(".");
    filename = Date.now() + '.' + extension[extension.length-1];
    cb(null, filename);
  }
});

router.post('/', multer({storage: storage, dest: './uploads/'}).single('uploads'), function(req,res){
  var music = new Music ({
    fieldname: req.file.fieldname,
    originalname: req.file.originalname,
    encoding: req.file.encoding,
    mimetype: req.file.mimetype,
    destination:req.file.destination,
    filename: req.file.filename,
    path: req.file.path,
    size: req.file.size
  })
  music.save(function(err){
    if (err){console.log(err)}
    else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  })
});
```

music model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var musicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fieldname: String,
  originalname: String,
  encoding: String,
  mimeptype: String,
  destination: String,
  filename: String,
  path: String,
  size: Number,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
var Music = mongoose.model('Music', musicSchema);

module.exports = Music;
```

index.ejs

```
<form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <input type="file" name="uploads">
  <input type="submit" value="Uploads">
</form>

<% for(var i = 0; i < musics.length; i++){ %>
  <p> <%= musics[i].originalname %> </p>

  <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
  <audio controls="controls">
    <source src="<%= musics[i].path %>"/>
  </audio>

<%}%>
```

this is the data in my mongo db

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576e27051ca343b201992472"), "created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-25T06:39:02.004Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-25T06:39:02.004Z"), "fieldname" : "uploads", "originalname" : "Trance - Tricky Tricky.mp3", "encoding" : "7bit", "destination" : "./uploads/", "filename" : "1466836741963.mp3", "path" : "uploads/1466836741963.mp3", "size" : 3818213, "__v" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
  <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
  <audio controls="controls">
    <source src="<%= musics[i].path %>"/>
  </audio>
to

  <audio autoplay="autoplay"controls="controls">
    <source src="<%= musics[i].path %>"/>
  </audio>
```

Comment: i tried taking the autoplay off. it now displays in index.ejs but it doesnt play the song. the audio controls are displaying but the play button is disabled, and the volume icon has a slash across it.